# How to create GWT Tooltip programmatically in Java code

Tags: java, gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I'm using GwtBootstrap3 for a GWT application and want to have something like this

```
<b:Tooltip title="I am a Tooltip!">
   <b:Button addStyleNames="{style.margin}" text="I have a Tooltip! (top)"/>
</b:Tooltip>
```

but programmatically in JAVA like this

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(); 
tooltip.setTitle = "I am a Tooltip";
```

My problem is that I cannot find a solution to add a SafeHtml String (like the Button) to tooltip and how to convert the tooltip to SafeHtml too. Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you need SafeHtml ? You can do new Tooltip(myButton) or tooltip.setWidget(myButton)

Answer (score 0):

`Tooltip`support only a `String` message (like a real tooltip). If you want to set SafeHtml, you need to use a `Popover`:

```
<b:Popover content="..." isHtml="true">
```

or create your own tooltip...

Answer (score -1):

GWT tooltip is basically a popup.
You can create your CustomTooltip by extend the `PopupPanel`. You can add the widgets in Custom tooltip.

You need to create the new instance to show the CustomTooltip and attch to the corresponding widget. This makes you DOM heavy (each time you are creating the new instance).